# AngularJS(Angular 1) compartir Informacion

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

tengo el siguiente codigo

AngularJS

```
 var aplicacion = angular.module('app',[])
aplicacion.factory('datosCompartidos', function (){
  var datosCompartidos = {}
  datosCompartidos.contador = 0
  datosCompartidos.getContador = function(){
    return datosCompartidos.contador
  }
  setInterval(function check(){
        datosCompartidos.contador +=1
    console.log(datosCompartidos.contador)
    }, 1000);//cada 1 minuto
  return datosCompartidos
})

aplicacion.controller('profile',['$scope','datosCompartidos',function($scope,datosCompartidos){
  $scope.m = datosCompartidos.contador
}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="profile">
    {{m}}

  </div>
 </div>
```

Mi problema es que el valor de m en el $scope no se actualiza, como deberia hacer, deberia agregar algun $watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que tendrias que hacer para que se actualice en otros controladores es usar el $rootScope con el $on algo asi..

- esto lo pones en los controladores que quieres que se actualice la variable

> $rootScope.$on('table_variable', function(event, obj) {
>   $scope.m = obj.variable;   });

- y con este lo ejecutas desde cualquier controlador y le envías el parámetro a actualizar

> $rootScope.$broadcast('update_variable', {variable : 'nuevo valor'});

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas cosas que debes arreglar. Primero, tienes un intervalo que quieres que se ejecute cada 1 minuto, sin embargo le estas pasando 1 segundo. El tiempo, tanto en `setInterval` como en `setTimeout` se da en milisegundos, por tanto seria 60000. Lo otro es que si `m` no se actualiza sola, deberias probar colocando el contador dentro del controlador, al fin y al cabo, no hay mucho codigo y si aun asi no se actualiza, puedes llamar la funcion `$scope.$apply( function() { $scope.m = ...; } )` y esa si lo actualiza de inmediato.

Comment: buneas, muchas gracias por contestar el tema es que yo quiero usar la variable en otros controladores tambien y que se actualize en todos a la vez